Upgrading from 20.04 LST to 22.04 LTS fails
On a POWER9 powerpc64le orginally install with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS trying to upgrade to next LTS 22.04.
Seems to have a broken dependency between language-pack-en and language-pack-en-base:
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  language-pack-en-base : Depends: language-pack-en 
     (>= 1:20.04+20220818) but 1:20.04+20220211 is to be installed
  Conflicts: language-pack-en 
     (< 1:20.04+20220818) but 1:20.04+20220211 is to be installed
E: Broken packages

Tried:

sudo apt upgrade -f language-pack-en-base

already. Which gave me the message above.
The sequence leading up to this point includes:
ubuntu@pceclib1:~$ sudo do-release-upgrade -c 
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
New release '22.04.3 LTS' available.
Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.

ubuntu@pceclib1:~$ sudo do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release 
Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.

ubuntu@pceclib1:~$ apt list --upgradable -a 
Listing... Done
language-pack-en-base/focal-updates 1:20.04+20220818 all   
   [upgradable from: 1:20.04+20220211]
language-pack-en-base/now 1:20.04+20220211 all 
   [installed,upgradable to: 1:20.04+20220818]
language-pack-en-base/focal 1:20.04+20200416 all

ubuntu@pceclib1:~$ sudo apt upgrade -f language-pack-en-base 
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done 
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.

Any ideas on how to resolve this circular dependency?
The command: $ sudo apt rdepends language-pack-en lists:
language-pack-en
Reverse Depends:
  Replaces: language-pack-en (<< 1:20.04+20220211)
  Replaces: language-pack-en-base (<< 1:20.04+20220211)
  Conflicts: language-pack-en-base (<< 1:20.04+20220211)
  Depends: language-pack-en-base (>= 1:20.04+20220211)
  Depends: language-pack-en-base (>= 1:20.04+20220818)
  Replaces: language-pack-gnome-en-base (<< 1:20.04+20220818)
  Replaces: language-pack-gnome-en (<< 1:20.04+20220818)
  Depends: language-pack-gnome-en
  Replaces: language-pack-en-base (<< 1:20.04+20220818)
  Conflicts: language-pack-en-base (<< 1:20.04+20220818)
  Replaces: language-pack-en (<< 1:20.04+20200416)
  Depends: language-pack-kde-en
  Replaces: language-pack-gnome-en-base (<< 1:20.04+20200416)
  Replaces: language-pack-gnome-en (<< 1:20.04+20200416)
  Depends: language-pack-gnome-en
  Replaces: language-pack-en-base (<< 1:20.04+20200416)
  Conflicts: language-pack-en-base (<< 1:20.04+20200416)
  Depends: language-pack-en-base (>= 1:20.04+20200416)

and sudo apt rdepends language-pack-en-base list:
language-pack-en-base
Reverse Depends:
  Depends: language-pack-en (>= 1:20.04+20220211)
  Replaces: language-pack-en-base (<< 1:20.04+20220211)
  Replaces: language-pack-en
  Replaces: language-pack-en-base (<< 1:20.04+20220818)
  Replaces: language-pack-gnome-en-base (<< 1:20.04+20220818)
  Replaces: language-pack-gnome-en (<< 1:20.04+20220818)
  Depends: language-pack-en (>= 1:20.04+20200416)
  Replaces: firefox-locale-en
  Replaces: language-pack-gnome-en-base (<< 1:20.04+20200416)
  Replaces: language-pack-gnome-en (<< 1:20.04+20200416)
  Replaces: language-pack-en-base (<< 1:20.04+20200416)
  Replaces: language-pack-en
  Replaces: firefox-locale-en


un block quoted the text. The damn formated mucks the console text up again.

I hate mark down ...

Your system is rather outdated it appears; I note 22.04.3 mentioned in your paste for the upgrade so was your copy/pasted detail taken ~six months ago?  as 22.04.4 is the current version and its soon changing to 22.04.5..  Correct package is language-pack-en-base | 1:20.04+20220818 | focal-updates  | source, all for one detail yet your system isn't showing that; meaning an non-upgraded system or incorrect/outdated sources being used & thus upgrades not applied.  I'd return to basics and sudo apt update & confirm no issues there (no missing lines, sources up-to-date & good mirrors etc)

This is a disk constrained VM image at OSU. Had problems updating without deleting most of my files. Just recently got the disk quantum bumped so i can do this upgrade. Yes I have done the apt update/upgrade multiple times each time with this result. i can trry again but suspect this will not help.

My project https://github.com/open-power-sdk/pveclib needs to test multiple compiler versions across multiple PowerISA versions. I have access to a POWER10 wilt 24.04, but can't use that due to other (compiler version) dependencies. I need 22.04 because that is where the most compilers will install.

I agree with @guiverc: The output does not look like a "circular dependency." It looks like some non-Ubuntu software depends upon the older version.

So how would I find that dependency?

Ran sudo apt rdepends language-pack-en

But the listing is too long to fit in a comment

Am I tangled up in between gnome and kde language-packs? See append to original text.

I believe the fact that you've prevented all package upgrades is your problem, ie. your fixes to space issues have created this problem. I suggest you fix your space issues & fully upgrade your existing 20.04 system & try again...   Checking sources as I stated earlier; ensuring you have no holds (apt-mark showhold) etc.  Your details match a Ubuntu based system and not a true Ubuntu system as I see it. Possibly the changes were consequences of changes made to deal with space issues thus self-inflicted; read your notes on changes made in dealing with space issues & revert those.

This was alway LTS, Started out as 18.04 LTS then upgraded to 20.04. Lots ot compilers and tools installed since. I dont have the authory to bump disk storage at OSU, This was done by the OSU admin but I assume that only affected the VM instance config which would not cause this..

Tried remove all the extra (non-ubuntu) packages I could find. then tried the update again. Same problem.
